# using shift+tab in a list changes focus

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a standard preset build of ckeditor with tab, indent, indentlist, indentblock plugins, with tabSpaces set to 0. Very frequently, while in a bulleted or numbered list, hitting shift+tab to unindent would unindent the list item but also move the cursor focus to something else on the page (a button, another form input unrelated to ckeditor, even the browser location bar). 
Using the classic editor in an iframe, so not sure what's happening. I've tried listening to the key event at priority 31 (seems like outdentlist has priority 30?) and canceling/stopping the event but doesn't work.

Comment: forgot to mention - using ckeditor 4.9.1

Comment: Please provide a working code snippet so that someone reviewing the problem doesn't have to guess what exactly you had in mind.

Comment: An example would be just on the ckeditor demo page for artifact editing: https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/#article, If i hit tab in the bulleted list it indents as expected, otherwise the cursor jumps all over the page. This seems to be the browser behavior for many web editors, so I guess what I'm asking is: is there a way to prevent this? (like catching the tab key event and canceling it)

Answer (score 1):

Just tried what i was doing before and it now works.(with 4.9.2, not sure if something was interfering before)

```
instance.on( 'key', function(e) {

    if (e.data.keyCode == 9 || e.data.keyCode == (CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 9)) {
        //trying to prevent tab and shift tab jumping focus out of editor
        e.cancel();
        e.stop();
    }         
 }, null, null, 31); //priority is after indent list plugin's event handler
```